# Not able to make tipc module

Tags: linux-kernel, tipc

I am not able to build tipc module when executed `Makefile` using `make` command in the path `/tipc-1.7.7-bundle/net/tipc`. The errors comes as `target not found`. I extracted the `tipc` 1.7 package in root directory. My operating system is CentOs 6.3. The Makefile contents are

---

```
#
# Makefile for the Linux TIPC layer
#

obj-$(CONFIG_TIPC) := tipc.o

tipc-y  += tipc_addr.o tipc_bcast.o tipc_bearer.o         tipc_cfgsrv.o  \
tipc_core.o tipc_handler.o tipc_link.o tipc_discover.o tipc_msg.o  \
tipc_name_distr.o tipc_topsrv.o tipc_name_table.o tipc_net.o  \
tipc_netlink.o tipc_node.o tipc_port.o tipc_ref.o  \
tipc_socket.o tipc_user_reg.o tipc_dbg.o tipc_eth_media.o

# End of file
```

---

Please help, i am newbie to linux.

Comment: Maybe the issue is *I extracted the tipc 1.7 package in root directory*

Comment: I extracted the files in non-root directory also, same problem is coming.

Comment: Hey, what does top directory in linux mean, i got the following command from tipc user guide "Use the Makefile under 
<topdir>/net/tipc"

Comment: I took a look to tipc: you must extract `tipc-1.7.7.tar.gz` at the top of linux kernel source. Then you should enable it by configure kernel for instance by using `make menuconfig` and browse in Networking->Networking folder. Then you can compile it by `make` that compile **entire kernel**. If you have non familiarity with linux kernel compilation is better if take a look to this topic before.

Comment: Hi, I didn't want to comile entire kernel. I want to bulid loadable module "tipc.ko" and load it to kernel. Loading is the second step. Firstly, I am not able to build the loadable module "tipc.ko".

Comment: Maybe you must do a first compilation to configure the environment. But I never do it on centos and I don't know if the package give to you a ready to use kernel tree. Try to compile it and see if it produce the module.

Comment: Hey, my path for the Makefile is "/tipc-1.7.7-bundle/net/tipc". Does the problem is coming beause "net" directory is inside directory "tipc-1.7.7-bundle". What is the exact location to do extraction of package "tipc-1.7.7.tar.gz"?

Comment: The package is ready to use kernel tree. It is mentioned in the user guide of package.

Comment: The path should be `net.tipc` and not `/tipc-1.7.7-bundle/net/tipc`. When you extrac `tipc-1.7.7.tar.gz` by `tar -xvf tipc-1.7.x.tar` from kernel source root it will overwrite `net/tipc` directory

Comment: There is am empty "net" folder in my root directory. I am not able to copy the contents inside this folder. How should i modify this folder. Like I said, I am newbie. :)

Comment: I mean `<kernel source>/net`: it cannot be empty.

Comment: "/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64/kernel/", is this the "kernel source" directory?

Comment: NO that is the location of module that was already build in kernel. Please take a look at http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules and http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source . Maybe here you will find all answer do you need.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I got the location where to place source files "/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64". But got same error "target not found" while "make", . Learn lot today.

Comment: My aim is to build "tipc.ko" loadable module.

Comment: Change `$(CONFIG_TIPC)` to `m` and try to build as `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules`

Comment: Thnaks, my problem is sloved :)